# Samsung Galaxy J3 SM-J320Y Bootloop Problem

Tags: samsung, boot-loop

I have a Samsung Galaxy J3 (SM-J320Y) and my friend tried to root it.. he uses Kingo Root Android and King Root but both of it failed to root it.. I already said to him not to bother rooting it but he continues and as he gives uo on trying to root it he unistalled the Kingo Root App and King Root. Then he restart my phone. the problem starts there, my phone has been on bootloop every since.. when its already at the samsung logo it would restart over and over again.. pls. help just bought this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It seems from what you have mentioned above, that your device was not rooted and thus there is no custom recovery installed on your device.
So here are the two methods which you can try -

Method-1

Step-1. Power OFF.

Step-2. Press and hold Power + Volume Up + Home.

Step-3. Select "wipe data factory reset".

Method-2

Download the stock ROM for your device and then flash it using software like Odin.
Here's the link to download the ROM- http://www.android.gs/download-stock-android-firmware-files-for-samsung-galaxy-j3-2016/

This will get your device to normal state.